# homework combinatorics carousel

Tags: combinatorics

I was asked this question in my homework:

How many different combinations are there to paint a carousel with $n$ seats, in $r$ different colors, such that any combination that you can get via rotating is considered the same combination?

Example: $red -> green -> blue$ is the same arrangement as $blue -> red -> green$

a) first question n=9
b) second question n=15
c) last question n=7

What I did:

I know the answer for n=7 (not because i understand it, but because someone told me) and it's a special case because 7 is a prime number...

I would love someone to explain to my why 7 is a special case, why does it matter if n is prime or not, and help me solve the question for n=9 and n=15.

The answer for n=7 is $\frac{r^7-r}{7}+r$

Comment: Have you heard of Burnside's lemma? It should solve your problem quite easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not prime (for example 6) you can break in up into repeating sections:  aka

$$a b c a b c$$
or
$$ababab$$
you can only do this for 7 if they are all the same color.  Understanding this should help answer the homework problem.

I realise this might not be enough of a hint so I will add to it.

The number of ways to paint the $7$ seats $r$ colors is $r^7$.  $r$ of these patterns are all of one color.  For the $r^7-r$ patterns where there is no real rotational symmetry, you can define the patterns that matter by their starting seat and find that there are severn duplicates of each pattern when you rotate it.  For the $r$ on colors each of these are identical.  You therefore end up with:

$$\frac{r^7-r}{7}+r$$ patterns.  When you change from 7 to other prime numbers you just change the 7 but if the number is not prime, you have to take into account patterns that have more complex rotation symetry that is not possible for 7.

Comment: Ok I think I am getting closer to understanding. if the number is for example 6, then im sure the answer is something along the lines of $\frac{r^6 - r}{6} + X$ where the X is something to do with the primes that make up 6 (2 and 3) but the question remains...what is X

Comment: I will say that the answer I get for 4 is: $$\frac{r^4-r-(r^2-r)}{4}+\frac{r^2-r}{2}+r$$.  Note that I split it up by 1, 2, and 4 where I split up 7 by 1 and 7.  I will post the one for 6 when I derive it. Burnside's lemma might be the correct but I don't know it.

Comment: I don't understand how you got your answer

Comment: On the one in the comments, the first part is the ones with no symmetry like with 7 (form abcd or abba or abbb etc). The second part is the ones of form abab. The final part is the "all the same color" as with the last part of the formula for 7. Note that the second part (plus the third part) is identical to the answer if n=2.  (I believe the answer for n=4 is reminisent of the answer for n=9)

Comment: why no symmetry is $\frac{r^4 - r - (r^2 -r)}{4}$? explain your calculation.

Comment: I believe the answer for 6 is $$\frac{r^6-r^3-r^2+r}{6}+\frac{r^3-r}{3}+\frac{r^2-r}{2}+r$$.  This uses the same logic as was decribed to explain the answer for 7 but is split into the 4 nessesary sections: 6, 3, 2, and 1.  aka forms like (aaaaab), (aabaab), (ababab) and (aaaaaa)

Comment: There are $r^4$ total.  $r$ of one color.  $r^2-r$ of the form $abab$.  So the final remaining category must contain: $r^4-r-r^2+r$.  I've given enough equations to answer the entire problem so i should probably stop as the guys in meta tend to frown on that.  I will answer any specfic questions but will be hesistant to provide any direct answers.

Comment: Ah I think I understand, so for 9 I should get $\frac{r^9 - (r^3 - r)}{9} + \frac{r^3 - r}{3} + r$

Comment: not quite...$\frac{r^9 - r-(r^3 - r)}{9} + \frac{r^3 - r}{3} + r$  If it helps, you should alway get 1 when $r=1$.