# Coloring round carousel with $p$ chairs using $b$ colors

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to tackle the following question, but to no avail...

> Let $p$ be some number of chairs in round carousel and let $b$ be some number of colors.
>
> Compute the number of different ways to color the chairs, given that two coloring are identical if one can be obtained from the other by rotating the carousel.

So, Iv'e seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560412/homework-combinatorics-carousel) and I understand the proof for prime $p$ (I also deduced it by myself), but I can't deduce the general formula for any integer $p$.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This is the problem of colouring necklaces, which you can read about e.g. at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29) and [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Necklace.html).

Comment: This link at [MSE Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions#13335) has a number of examples.